# Countable metric space and space of all rational numbers.

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I know that uncountable metric space can not be homeomorphic to a subspace of the space of $\mathbb{Q}$ of all rational numbers.

but can this be true for countable metric space?

Comment: Yes, every countable metric space can be embedded in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: thank,Is there is any standard homeomorphism that we can define ?(not sure is standard is the right word here).

Comment: @Brian, Birkary But not isometrically, even if we restrict to spaces where all distances are rational.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Good point, I wonder what condition should be added to be isometrically ( at least to the space ), I don't think the same cardinality work.

Comment: @Birkary: Not really, no. If you’re curious, [this paper](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.htm) has a nice treatment of the case in which the countable metric space has no isolated points, which is needed as a special case anyway in proving the general result.

Comment: @Andrés: True. I’ve a bad habit of thinking just in terms of the topology, essentially reading *metric* as *metrizable*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks, today I saw this paper, but now I am more curious about,I will read it more deeply.